# Reuse objects within same powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint

I'm making a powerpoint presentation, and there's a flowchart (some boxes, arrows, text, formatting) that I'd like to reuse in other slides. Is there a way to make it once (say on slide 2), group it, and re-use it on subsequent slides, such that changes on slide 2 are propagated to other slides? I'd like to have the freedom to rescale the group, so putting it on the template doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to select all the pieces, right click, and choose group?

Comment: PowerPoint won't do this on its own. It'd probably be possible to write code that looks for certain shapes/groups "tagged" as "parent" shapes then look for "child" shapes, delete the child shapes, paste copies of the parent shapes.